# How to use wildcards with SQLite paramaters?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use wildcards with parameters in SQLite.

Here's the code I'm trying to get working:

```
@GamePara='Desert';
SELECT
    GameName
FROM Games
WHERE GameName LIKE '%' + @GamePara + '%';
```

This code returns no results. It is supposed to return all fields which include the string `'Desert'` in `GameName`.

If I replace the parameter with the desired value directly, as shown below, I am able to get the desired results.

```
SELECT
    GameName
FROM Games
WHERE GameName LIKE '%Desert%';
```

I've not had much experience with SQL parameters in general, so it's possible that my issue could exist with other versions of SQL as well.

MODERATOR EDIT:
Note: It is very bad habit to delete question after getting correct answer.

USER EDIT: Sorry, I hadn't seen that the question had been answered when I deleted it (I hadn't refreshed the page). I deleted the question because I realised that I asked the wrong question. The issue that I was having was that I couldn't set parameters the same way as in MySQL. (`@GamePara='Desert';` returned the message `Error: near "@GamePara": syntax error`). I had tried the `||` concatenation, but the parameter setting was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`||`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) for string concatenation:

> The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings
>   of its operands.

```
@GamePara='Desert';
SELECT
    GameName
FROM Games
WHERE GameName LIKE '%' || @GamePara || '%';
```

Compare:

```
SELECT 'a' + 'b', 'a' || 'b'
-- 0 vs ab
```